# Is int equivalent to int* in structure and name equivalency?

Tags: c++, pointers, types

I am trying to understand type equivalency (structure, name, internal name). One thing that I cannot seem to grasp is how pointers and non-pointers related. For example; if in C/C++ I had the following declarations,

```
int  x;
int* y;
```

My understanding is that x is of type int and y is a pointer to a memory location that houses an int. My intuition then is that a pointer, of any type, is not structurally equivalent to its base type or am I wrong in this understanding?

Comment: What do you mean by structural equivalency? Also, what do you mean by name equivalency?

Comment: The finger pointing to the moon is not equivalent to the moon.

Comment: a pointer just tells you how to interpret the bytes at a certain memory address.  But those words you're using don't have any real meaning "structure, name, internal name" in c++, so no one really understands what you're saying.

Comment: Fun trivia fact:  on most 64-bit machines, an `int` takes up 4 bytes of RAM, while an `int *` takes up 8 bytes of RAM.   Which is to say, their structures are quite different from each other.

Comment: @eerorika Structural, name and internal name equivalence are the basis for type checking in a programming language.